# Erro em retorno de dado binário BLOB do Postgres para PHP + HTML

Tags: php, html, postgresql

Estou executando em HTML com PHP um Projeto ERP que Via XAMPP o arquivo `Buscacurriculum.php` trará na tela a imagem e dados do colaborador empregado.

Mesangem:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on resource "C:\xampp\..." StackTrace: #0 {main}`

Código PHP

```php
<?php
  $HndCon=pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=cyberdynedb user=tst password=minhasenha");
  pg_exec($HndCon,"BEGIN");
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.fotos";
  $sth = $HndCon->query($sql);
  $result=pg_fetch_array($sth);
  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
?>
```

A tabela fotos contém as colunas `id`, `foto`, `oid`. Exitem dados cadastrados `(1, bynarydata, 33034)`.

A linha  `$sth = $HndCon->query($sql);` eu vi num outro post aqui no Stack e ajudou na execução mas o erro persiste.

Comment: A mensagem de erro parece-me incompleta. É isso mesmo? Tente [edit] a pergunta para fornecer mais detalhes.

Comment: Dentre os campos que você informou que existem em sua tabela não consta o campo :`image`

Comment: @LuizFelipe Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on resource "C:\xampp\htdocs\empresa\Buscainterna.php" StackTrace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\empresa\Buscainterna.php on line 37. A linha 37 é:  $sth = $HndCon->query($sql);

Comment: @anonimo. Alterando para fotos o erro persiste. Acredito não ser isso, não sei se pode ser algum evento restante em lógica booleana com Vetor, sigo sem resposta.

Comment: Qual o tipo de dado utilizado para o campo `foto` já que o PostgreSQL não possui o tipo de dado BLOB?

Comment: @anonimo eu cadastrei o formato JPG do diretório raiz C:\Temp e povoei o banco com este dado. Estou tentando analisar de é alguma condição booleana por vetor de strings. Mas nada até agora.